# Understanding virtual base classes and constructor calls

Tags: c++, virtual, multiple-inheritance, base-class

I'm a bit confused about how virtual base classes work.  In particular, I was wondering how the constructor of the base class gets called.  I wrote an example to understand it:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
using std::string;

struct A{
    string s;
    A() {}
    A(string t): s(t) {}
};

struct B: virtual public A{
    B(): A("B"){}
};

struct C: virtual public A {};

struct D: public B, public C {};

struct E: public C, public B {};

struct F: public B {};

int main(){
    D d;
    printf("\"%s\"\n",d.s.c_str());
    E e;
    printf("\"%s\"\n",e.s.c_str());
    F f;
    printf("\"%s\"\n",f.s.c_str());
    B b;
    printf("\"%s\"\n",b.s.c_str());
}
```

Which outputs

```
""
""
""
"B"
```

I wasn't sure what would happen in the first two cases, but for the third one at least I was expecting the output to be "B".  So now I'm just confused.  What are the rules for understanding how the constructor of A gets called?

Comment: The last case, for struct F, wasn't discussed in that question, although maybe I should have understood it from the answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is always just **one** constructor call, and always of the actual, concrete class that you instantiate. It is *your* responsibility to endow each derived class with a constructor which calls the base classes' constructors if and as necessary, as you did in `B`'s constructor.

*Update:* Sorry for missing your main point! Thanks to ildjarn.

However, your `B` inherits *virtually* from `A`. According to the standard (10.1.4 in the FIDS), "for each distinct baseclass that is specified virtual, the most derived object shall contain a single base class subobject of that type". In your case this means that when constructing the base, your class `F` immediately calls `A`'s default constructor, not `B`'s.

Comment: How does this answer his question? `F`'s default constructor implcitly invokes `B`'s default constructor, which initializes `A::s` with `"B"`, but `f.s` is empty. I.e., his question is why does [this](http://ideone.com/3xQf4) print an empty string?

Comment: @ildjarn: You're right, sorry! It all hinges on `B` inheriting virtually from `A`. I will amend that!

Comment: @Ben: By default constructor. You could say `F::F() : B(...), A(...) { }`. See the comments in DeadMG's question + source examples. The default constructor (or whichever you specify) of `B` does get called, just not any calls to `A`'s constructor from within `B`'s constructor, since, as DeadMG nailed it, "the virtual baseclass is constructed by the most derived class", i.e. `F`.

Comment: @Kerrek : Technically, the virtual base subobject is initialized before the direct base subobject, so `F::F() : A(...), B(...) { }` would be better. I think GCC even gives a warning for `F::F() : B(...), A(...) { }`.

Answer (score 7):

Virtual base classes are *always* constructed by the most derived class.

Comment: And doesn't explain the exhibited behaviour at all.

Comment: @Tomalak : It does explain the exhibited behavior, because `C`, `D`, `E`, and `F` are responsible for initializing their `A` subobjects, and none do; consequently, their `A` subobjects are always default constructed, despite the red herring of the latter 3 inheriting from `B`.

Comment: @ildjarn: Oh, I get you. OK. Is `F` able to provide that parameter, then?

Comment: Very nice. Sorry for making a mess of this, this is a much better answer. Can you clarify: When `F` is instantiated, `B`'s default constructor does get called (to initialize the `B`'s objects), but with the exception of the call to `A(string)`?

Comment: @Tomalak : Yep, it's _not_ intuitive. :-] The semantics of virtual inheritance is one of the prime reasons multiple inheritance is not allowed in e.g. Java and C#.

Comment: @Kerrek : `B`'s constructor runs, it simply doesn't initialize its `A` subobject since in this context it is not the most derived type. See [here](http://ideone.com/g4Chk).

Comment: @ildjarn: Yes, I saw that the `A` subobject doesn't get initialized, but I was just wondering if that means effectively that all calls to `A(...)` in any of `B`'s constructors' initializer lists are ignored in constructors of descendants of `B`.

Comment: @ildjarn: Perhaps this is the crux of the peculiarity of virtual inheritance: Syntactically it looks like you're calling a function which is in turn calling another function, but that's not what's happening. A veritable gotcha! :-)

Comment: @Kerrek : I know you're clear on the situation now, but it occurs to me now (20 hours later :-P) that [this](http://ideone.com/L9l6A) would have been a better demonstration.