# Purpose of arguments to constructors of 2nd level classes in initialization list

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

I was experimenting with inheritance and I came across a particular behaviour. First, look at the code:

```
class animal
{
public:
    int ID;
    animal(int id) : ID(id)
    {
        cout<<"I am an animal and I am not a terrorist. Here is my ID: "
        <<ID<<endl;
    }
};

class lion : virtual public animal
{
public:
    lion(int id) : animal(id)
    {
        cout<<"I am a lion and I am not a terrorist. Here is my ID: "
        <<ID<<endl;
    }
};

class tiger : virtual public animal
{
public:
    tiger(int id) : animal(id)
    {
        cout<<"I am a tiger and I am not a terrorist. Here is my ID: "
        <<ID<<endl;
    }
};

class liger : public lion, public tiger
{
public:
    liger(int id) : lion(id), tiger(id), animal(id)
    {
        cout<<"I am a liger and I am not a terrorist. Here is my ID: "
        <<ID<<endl;
    }
};
```

When the constructor of liger was `liger(int id) : lion(id), tiger(id), animal(id)...`
and I created a object like `liger l(444)` then I got the following expected output:

```
I am an animal and I am not a terrorist. Here is my ID: 444
I am a lion and I am not a terrorist. Here is my ID: 444
I am a tiger and I am not a terrorist. Here is my ID: 444
I am a liger and I am not a terrorist. Here is my ID: 444
```

Then I changed it to to `liger(int id) : lion(55), tiger(55), animal(id)` but it too gave the same output. **Now, my question is, if the arguments to the `lion` and `tiger` constructors are neglected, then what is their purpose**?

Comment: As you use virtual inheritance, the constructor of base class is only called once is the most derived class.

Comment: [**See this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461784/understanding-virtual-base-classes-and-constructor-calls). Then, 1. how many places in your code do you see `ID` being **set** ? 2. How many places in your *output* do you see that function being invoked ? 3. Why do you think that is? (ans: research when/how virtual base class constructors are fired in a hierarchy like yours.

Answer (score 0):

In virtual inheritance, the constructor of the virtual base is called by the constructor of *most derived* class, that's the constructor of `liger` in your case. The calls to `animal(id)` from `lion` and `tiger` constructors are ignored in this case. That's by design.

The reason for this is that you still want to call `animal(id)` when `tiger` or `lion` is the most derived class.

Answer (score 0):

Only the most derived class actually initializes the virtual baseclass. In other words, the initialization of animal performed by tiger and lion is ignored if (!) they are not the most derived class.