# Not to use default constructor for virtual base class

Tags: c++

I was looking at [Understanding virtual base classes and constructor calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461784/understanding-virtual-base-classes-and-constructor-calls) and I understand that the most derived class will call the top-base class default constructor directly. But is there a way not to call top-base default constructor?

One example for my problem,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

////// BEGIN LIBRARY CODE
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    }

    A(int)
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    }
};

class B : virtual public A
{
public:
    B()
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    }
};

class C: virtual public A
{
public:
    C()
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    }
};

class D: public B, public C
{
public:
    D(int x) : A(x), B(), C() // ok. works as expected
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    }
};
////// END LIBRARY CODE


////// USER CODE BEGINS

class E: public D
{
public:
    E() : D(42) // problem, invokes A(), not A(int)
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    }

    E(int x) : D(x) // same problem
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
    }
};
////// USER CODE ENDS

int main()
{
    D d(1);
    E e1,e2(42);
}
```

**Output**

```
A::A(int)
B::B()
C::C()
D::D(int)
A::A()
B::B()
C::C()
D::D(int)
E::E()
A::A()
B::B()
C::C()
D::D(int)
E::E(int)
```

**Problem:**

I want `E` to only care about `D` construction. But from the explanation in the beginning, if I don't add `A::A(int)` below, I will always use default constructor no matter how I update class D

```
E() : A(42), D(42) // works, but undesirable
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
}

E(int x) : A(x), D(x) // this works, but undesirable
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n';
}
```

In short, I don't want the user-code `class E` extending the library code `class D` to have to specify `class A` construction parameters so...

- Is there any way it can be done by a "middle" class in the inheritance chain such as class `D` in my example above, to alleviate the most-derived classes from having to do so?

Comment: You're the author. You can specify any initialization you like in the constructor initializer list.

Comment: `top-base` is not a valid identifier. Post real code please.

Comment: Instead of `top-base`, maybe you mean `A`?

Comment: I was able to get around the problem with a wrapper class, E has-a D, but that forces you to duplicate all of D's interface (and A,B,C) that you want to expose from E, which is worse.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor for the top-level class calls the constructors for all virtual bases. But that's no different from calling constructors for direct non-virtual bases: if you put in an explicit constructor call, that's what the compiler will use; if you don't, it will use the default constructor. So the answer is no, if the default constructor isn't appropriate, you can't avoid calling A's constructor from E.

Comment: By changing the design, possibly class `D` could use a data member and forwarding instead of direct inheritance, and that data member could be of a class inheriting `B` and `C`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf as I was rewriting the OP's code to make it legible and match the question, that was what I was thinking as well.

Comment: I suppose all that depends on what the question is perceived to be about. Changing a design is not an appropriate workaround for a coding problem, although running into a coding problem can be an indication of a design problem. But given the design in the question, the answer is simply no.